# Send data using writev() , receive data using readv()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Client:

1. I've used `write()` to send data from client -> server.
2. I need to determine the file size at the server which is the 3rd argument in `write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)`.
3. Should I use `writev()` to send the data from client -> server as separate buffers? `writev(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer))`? Is this the right approach?

   ```
    write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
   ```

Server:

1. On the server side, I'm reading the data using `read()`.
2. Should I use, `readv()` - to obtain the file size?

Comment: `writev('sockfd', 'buffer' and strlen(buffer))?`  No, `writev('sockfd', 'buffer', sizeof(buffer))`  `sizeof()` includes all bytes of a buffer, including nul terminator.  `strlen()` does not

Comment: Typically, if one needs to transmit *meta-data* (like the length of the data to transmit) one needs to invent a *protocol*. A simple protocol includes the length as a fixed-length integer in a specified byte-order, followed by the data itself.

Comment: It's hard to say what is the right approach, without understanding what you are trying to achieve.  What do you think using `readv()` and `writev()` would accomplish that `read()` and `write()` do not?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - I think writev() would send the data as a vector of buffers, where  buff [0] = 'sockd', buff[1] = 'buffer' and buff[2] = 'strlen(buffer)' . So whenever a 'newfile' is sent from the client, its 'filesize' would be determined, so as to allocate right amount of memory and also enable to copy file data at the right location.

Comment: It doesn't matter. TCP sends bytes. You send some bytes, some more bytes and some more bytes. It doesn't know about buffers. Buffers are just how you tell TCP which bytes to send.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - Send metadata of the file from the client before it is actually sent to the server

Comment: @Ace.McCloud sorry, `writev()` doesn't do any message-framing.  The bytes it sends willl be the same as if you had called `write()` separately for each buffer, and `writev()`'s guarantees about how many bytes may or may not get sent, and how they get grouped together, are the same (which is to say, there aren't any, in either case).  `writev()`'s only real benefit over `write()` is that it can (in some case) reduce the number of system calls your program has to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter. TCP sends bytes. You send some bytes, some more bytes and some more bytes. It doesn't know about buffers. Buffers are just how you tell TCP which bytes to send.

When you use writev with 3 buffers, you're telling TCP to send the bytes in the first buffer and then the bytes in the second buffer and then the bytes in the third buffer. They all get joined together. Same as if you told it to write one big buffer.

If you want to send two things at once (like a file size and then file data) then writev can be more convenient, or not. Note that writev can decide to stop writing at any point in any buffer, and you have to call it again to write the rest. That makes it not very convenient.

And it has no relevance to the server either. The server is allowed to read the bytes into one buffer and then a second buffer if the first one fills up and then a third buffer if the second one fills up. Or it can read them into one big buffer. TCP doesn't care - they're the same bytes either way.

readv has the same problem as writev where it might only read the first one and a half buffers, instead of all 3 at once, and then you have to call it again and tell it to read the second half of the second buffer and the entire third buffer.

Comment: "Note that writev can decide to stop writing at any point in any buffer" That doesn't sound true at all

Comment: @TZubiri it's true for write and it's also true for writev. Why don't you think it's true for writev? For example, the kernel will stop writing to a socket when the send buffer is full.

Comment: You'll get an error before any writing occurs. The operation is atomic.

Comment: @TZubiri that is false. What return value do you get if you try to writev, say, 100MB of data to a socket? (100MB just to make sure it's *really* above the send buffer size)

Comment: ENOSPC? "The device containing the file referred to by fd has no room for the data.
"

Comment: @TZubiri did you try it?